# Error:Android Packager: [...] java.io.FileNotFoundException:... (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, import

I just imported a project from Mercurial in Android Studio (via checkout). The problem I initially had was that the "APK path" was not set.

What I did to solve this is go to

> "Project structure" > "Modules" > "Android" > "Packaging" > "APK path"

And I set that to my project bin folder (*C:\Users\Bart\IdeaProjects\VMT\SPC\SPC\bin*)

Now I get the error:

```
Error:Android Packager: [SPC] java.io.FileNotFoundException:
C:\Users\Bart\IdeaProjects\VMT\SPC\SPC\bin (Permission denied)
```

I tried to start IntelliJ as administrator, but no success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I emptied the field "APK path", then I went to "Modules" > "SPC" (project name) > and put the output path to an absolute path instead of a relative path "/production/spc".